# "Junk food" vs "processed food"

Tags: synonyms

According to Wikipedia, the term ***junk food***

> dates back at least to the early 1950s, although its coinage has been credited to Michael F. Jacobson of the Center for Science in the Public Interest, in 1972. It refers to anything made principally of (1) ***white flour*** and or (2) ***refined white sugar*** or ***syrup***. For example, *white bread, crackers, cake, candy, ice cream soda, chocolate malted, sundaes, sweetened carbonated beverages*.

([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/junk-food)) adds the denotation of speed in preparing this food:

> food that is unhealthy but is quick and easy to eat

On the other hand, ***processed food*** seems to have a similar negative connotation:

> Processed food has had some sort of chemical or industrial treatment in order to cook it, preserve it, or improve its taste or appearance:
>
> - highly ***processed*** convenience foods

My question is: *Can **junk food** be used as a synonym of **processed food** to mean *unhealthy food* in non-scientific contexts?* Do they belong to the same register of language (my feeling is that ***junk food*** is less formal)? To be more concrete, can we swap the two expressions in these examples:

> I Cut Out ***Processed Food*** [Junk Food?] for a Month to Quit My ‘Healthy’ Eating Habits ([source](https://www.wellandgood.com/cut-out-processed-foods/))

> I do not eat ***junk foods*** [processed foods?] or stuff like that during cheat days. ([source](https://www.myproana.com/index.php/topic/2161378-taking-cheat-days-body-rejecting-unhealthy-food/))

Comment: You may want to adjust. A dictionary definition unhedged by 'often' etc is a denotation (although polysemy complicates). / 'Quick and easy to eat' doesn't say anything about preparation time ('quick to prepare and easy to eat' would be needed). // I can't see that 'processed food' really fits the register of your second query sentence.

Comment: All tinned foods are processed but not all of them are junk foods. For example tinned pulses such as chickpeas and haricot beans are as nutritious as dried and reconstituted ones. However baked  beans, which are tinned haricot beans in a tomato sauce, are considered to be less healthy because of the large amounts of sugar and salt often found in the sauce.

Comment: There’s *processed* and there’s *highly* processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be used as a synonym; what can be said is that "processed food" can sometimes be not as healthy as other food. This [source](https://www.nhs.uk/live-well/eat-well/what-are-processed-foods/) makes this clear.

> Food processing can be as basic as:
>
> - freezing
> - canning
> - baking
> - drying
>
> Not all processed foods are unhealthy but some processed foods may contain high levels of salt, sugar and fat.
>
> What counts as processed food?
>
> Examples of common processed foods include:
>
> - breakfast cereals
> - cheese
> - tinned vegetables
> - bread
> - savoury snacks, such as crisps, sausage rolls, pies and pasties
> - meat products, such as bacon, sausage, ham, salami and paté
> - microwave meals or ready meals
> - cakes and biscuits
>   -drinks, such as milk or soft drinks
>
> Not all processed food is a bad choice. Some foods need processing to make them safe, such as milk, which needs to be pasteurised to remove harmful bacteria.
>
> Other foods need processing to make them suitable for use, such as pressing seeds to make oil.

It is obvious that the processes are, for the most important ones, those used for a lot of food considered healthy,  and that such items as breakfast cereals, sliced bread or cheese can't be called junkfood. The nutritional value of bread products, cheese and cereals is unquestioned.

> ([Junk-Food Facts](https://www.webmd.com/diet/features/junk-food-facts#1)) "Junk food" generally refers to foods that contribute lots of calories but little nutritional value. Of course, what's considered "junk food" depends on whom you ask. Some might say pizza is junk food, for example. But I personally don't think so, since it contributes real food with nutrients, like cheese and tomato sauce. Add whole-wheat or part whole-wheat crust, plus veggies as a topping, and I'd say pizza completely exits the junk food category.

Comment: I would add *cooking* as a form of processing. Just not preprocessing.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that's another process that has no appreciable negative effect on food, except some loss of vitamins.

Comment: I think the difference between cooking and the listed forms of processing is that cooking is often done at home before eating, while the other methods are generally done in a factory or commercial kitchen (even baking bread). It is certainly possible to buy pre-cooked foods, but many foods are purchased raw and cooked at home.